# CollectionView al declarar celda no reusable error "Unexpectedly found while unwrapping an Optional value"

Tags: swift

Estoy implementando una función con collectionView para que me muestre una cantidad de Celdas.

Tengo el problema que si la celda la declaro como reutilizable `"dequeueReusableCell"` al hacer scroll vertical las celdas que desaparecen al volverla a mostrar algunas imagenes de botones se intercambian por otras celdas.

Creo haber visto un código en alguna parte que esto se solucionaba diferenciando cada celda con su tag y luego mostrandolas segun un orden. 
Otra solución era no haciendo las celdas reusables.

Quería solucionarlo no reusando celdas con `cellForItem(at: indexPath)` de esta manera:

```
cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! MyCell
```

pero cuando estoy ejecutando el programa y me tiene que mostrar las celdas se corta mostrando el siguiente error:

> "Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional
>   value"

¿Cual es el error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

habría que ver como has implementado el método cellForRowAtIndexPath. Creo que es ahi donde vas a tener el problema y o no actualizas los datos o el modelo de datos lo tienes mal. No intentes hacer algo diferente que no te va a funcionar. Te pongo unejemplo de este método

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   //obtienes la celda que vas a reutilizar
   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyCellId", for: indexPath) as! MyCell
   //tienes que obtener lo que quieres mostrar en esta celda
   let item = loQueSeaDeDondeSeaParaElIndexPath: indexPath
   //asignas valores a la celda
   cell.nombre = item.nombre
   cell.edad = item.edad
   .....
   return cell
}
```

Habría que ver también como has registrado la celda en la tabla, te pongo un ejemplo:

```
let nib = UINib(nibName: "MyCell", bundle: nil)
self.tableView.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "MyCellId")
```

Acabo de darme cuenta que es una collectionView, pero seria similar.
El metodo cellForItem(at: indexPath) que indicas es para obtener la celda del indexpath que le pasas

Comment: no entiendo la parte "let item  = loQueseaDeDondeSeaParaElIndexPath: indexPath". A que te refieres con loQueseaDeDondeSeaParaelIndexPath ? Yo esa parte la tengo con un array donde voy cogiendo los datos tal como asi: cell.nombre = self.miLista[indexPath.item].nombre : cell.edad = self.miLista[indexPath.item].edad: return cell

Comment: Despues me muestra X celdas con sus datos rellenos perfectamente. En cada celda hay un boton que al pulsarlo le quiero cambiar la imagen y es ahi donde tengo el problema. Tengo el boton con un IBAction dentro de la declaracion de la celda que al pulsarlo le cambio la imagen. me la cambia todo correcto. Pero al hacer luego el scroll y desaparecer la celda cuando vuelve a aparecer el boton con la imagen cambiada esta en otra celda.

Comment: Por eso queria usar el "collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! MyCell" en vez del "collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyCellId", for: indexPath) as! MyCell" Pero me sale el error cuando esta apunto de rellenar la celda.

Comment: La celda la tengo declarada en el CollectionView del Storyboard no por codigo nib. ¿ Donde tendria que implementar el cambio de imagen del boton entonces ? ¿ Dentro del codigo de la celda de MyCell ? o ¿ En la misma vista que declaro el collectionView que recoge la Cell ?

Comment: a lo primero. si, los datos los sacas asi, pero eso de indexpath.ítem? no seria indexpath.row?

Comment: a lo segundo, lo suyo es que el target del botón no apunte a la celda, que apunte al controlador y con un tag (que lo suyo seria el indexpath.row) sabes desde que celda hanpulsado. Y entonces además de cambiar la celda, tienes que cambiar el modelo, para que cuando vuelas a pasar por ahí te pinte la nueva imagen y no la antigua

Comment: a lo ultimo, si la tienes declarada en el xib, no pasa nada, solo asegúrate de que tengas rellenado el nombre en el reusablecelld del xib

Comment: Habia leido que para collectionView se ponia indexPath.item en vez de row ya que row es mas para tableView. Tengo las celdas distribuidas en un espacio de 4 x 3 de todas maneras si pongo .row o .item me hace el mismo fallo.

Comment: En resumen: Cuando cargo el modelo en las celdas las muestras todas bien. Si cambio el estado de una celda y hago scroll (desaparece y vuelve a aparecer la celda)  el estado se intercambia con la de otra celda ( supongo porque reusara otra ). ¿ Cuando hago scroll no tengo que volver a cargar el modelo en las celdas pues ya estan cargadas no ?  Si hago un cambio del modelo y luego un reloadData() para cargar de nuevo las celdas con nuevos datos tambien me intercambia datos en las celdas. Estoy buscando informacion pero no he encontrado ningun ejemplo de lo que estoy haciendo en otras webs

Comment: Tienes que cambiar el modelo. La celda cuando desaparezca se borra de memoria y se reutiliza para la siguiente. Cuando vuelvas para atrás, se volverá a cargar del modelo de datos. Si no modificaste el modelo para esa celda pues volverá a aparecer el dato antiguo

Comment: ENCONTRE EL ERROR !! No le había dado un valor por defecto a la imagen del cell del boton, creia que con la imagen por defecto ya puesta en el Storyboard con el Cell era suficiente.